# Finding minimum distance of a point from a cone in a given plane

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, solid-geometry

I have been working on a research idea for sometime where I need to optimize a given situation. I have reduced it down to finding the closest point on a curve from a given point(P). The curve is made from the intersection of a given sphere(S) and a given cone(C). P lies on the surface of the S.

I have been working on this problem statement and I simplified this problem into finding the minimum distance from a point(centre of sphere S) to the surface of cone along a plane. However, I am unable to find a generalized method of solving this problem. Will be great if someone could help :D

In this I know the plane equation,cone equation,sphere equation and the point P.
It will be great even if you can only provide a symbolic algorithm.

[Images](http://www.grad.hr/geomteh3d/prodori/prodor_sf_eng.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

$$
p = (x,y,z)\\
p_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0)\\
C\to x^2+y^2 = z^2\\
S\to (x - 3)^2 + y^2 + (z - 1)^2 = 10
$$

Using the Lagrange multipliers, this problem can be stated as

$$
L(x,y,\lambda,\mu) = ||p-p_0||^2+\lambda(x^2+y^2 - z^2)+\mu( (x - 3)^2 + y^2 + (z - 1)^2 - 10)
$$

with stationary points given by the solutions of

$$
\nabla L = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 2 \mu  (x-3)+2 (x-3)+2 \lambda  x=0 \\
 2 (y-5)+2 \lambda  y+2 \mu  y=0 \\
 2 (z-5)+2 \mu  (z-1)-2 \lambda  z=0 \\
 x^2+y^2-z^2=0 \\
 (x-3)^2+y^2+(z-1)^2-10=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Attached a plot showing the solutions.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & z & ||p-p_0|| \\
 0.206925 & 0.380531 & -0.433153 & 7.65898 \\
 0.475273 & -1.73045 & 1.79453 & 7.87072 \\
 1.55558 & -0.727696 & -1.71737 & 8.94516 \\
 2.63556 & 2.07762 & 3.35599 & 3.37282 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see you solved it for a more difficult case by not taking in some additional information.

Comment: @HimanshuSharma  If you have this additional information, please show us it. The poin location, the plane, the sphere and the cone.

Comment: The point is inside the conical volume and I have to solve for all the possible planes that can pass through this point. The best thing would be to find a generalised solution which you have very well done. One thing, this method of solving is perhaps computationally expensive(which is a major factor as I am working with systems of response time <100ms). That's why I tried reducing the problem into a two dimensional plane. If you have any geometric intuition of solving the 2D problem by any linear method (computationally inexpensive) then that would be great.